# Print out an Article based on the supplied id

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, persistence

I am trying to print out an article based on the supplied id. I have a method getArticleById which returns the article if it exists or returns null if it doesn't exist. I also have a start() method which prompts the user to enter an id and prints out the article if it exists. I'm not sure if I have implemented the getArticleById correctly. Also, I need some direction start() method to check whether the id that was entered exists or not.

```
public Article getArticleById(int id, Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
            "SELECT * FROM articles  WHERE id = ?")) {
        stmt.setInt(1, id);
        try (ResultSet r = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            if (r.next()) {
                return getAllArticles(conn).get(id);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } 
    }
}

private void start() throws IOException, SQLException {
    try (Connection conn = DBConnectionUtils.getConnectionFromSrcFolder("connection.properties")) {
        System.out.print("Enter the article id: > ");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(Keyboard.readInput());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good, you just need to invoke your `getArticleById` method in `start`:

```
private void start() throws IOException, SQLException {
    try (Connection conn = DBConnectionUtils.getConnectionFromSrcFolder("connection.properties")) {
        System.out.print("Enter the article id: > ");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(Keyboard.readInput());
        Article article = getArticleById(id, conn);
        // DO SOMETHING WITH ARTICLE
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.